# editDocumentWithProgID2 in CSOM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, office-365, provider-hosted-app, word

I need to Open/Download Word or PowerPoint Document directly from **Provider Hosted SharePoint App**. We can perform easily in on-premise using **editDocumentWithProgID2**

Tried with getting **CORE.js**, **SP.js** and other related js files from 15 hive and placed in solution with referencing inside the aspx page.

```
<script src="../Scripts/js/SP.Init.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/js/SP.Core.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/js/SP.Runtime.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/js/SP.js"></script>    
<script src="../Scripts/js/CORE.JS"></script>
```

This below function is called on anchor tag in javascript.

```
function EditDocumentFile(filename) {                        
        editDocumentWithProgID2(filename, '', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', '0', '/', '0');
    }

function editDocumentWithProgID2(strDocument, varProgID, varEditor, bCheckout, strhttpRoot, strCheckouttolocal) {            

        var sURL = unescape(window.location.pathname);
        window.location.href = sURL;           

        var errorCode = editDocumentWithProgIDNoUI(strDocument, varProgID, varEditor, bCheckout, strhttpRoot, strCheckouttolocal);            

        if (errorCode == 1) {
            alert(L_EditDocumentRuntimeError_Text);
            window.onfocus = RefreshOnNextFocus;
        }
        else if (errorCode == 2)
            alert(L_EditDocumentProgIDError_Text);
    }
```

Not working and shows error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: unescapeProperly is not defined

in browser developer tool console.

Any idea how to work with **editDocumentWithProgID2** in CSOM ?

Comment: Can you check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/1842937/1294606

Comment: Thanx Atish, Yes I already have done this way. The reference which you gave would work only for on-premise. Let me edit my question again.

Comment: is your requirement only to open/download document whenever users will click on the link? if so, then I have a alternative solution for you

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: Do you have document URL already?

Comment: In filename parameter I get the document URL like "http://serverurl/Local Library/SharePoint 2013 Installation Guide.docx"

Comment: See my answer. Try and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment, I am writing an alternative solution.

Add `?web=1` or `?web=0` for open or download your document.

- `web=0` means file will be downloaded when you hit this URL in browser.
- `web=1` means file will be opened in browser using office online.

**Example**

Let's say your document URL is `serverurl/Local Library/SharePoint 2013 Installation Guide.docx`, Now create the `<a>` like following for opening this document

```
<a href="serverurl/Local Library/SharePoint 2013 Installation Guide.docx?web=1">file Name</a>
```

For downloading

```
<a href="serverurl/Local Library/SharePoint 2013 Installation Guide.docx?web=0">file Name</a>
```

Comment: Yes I thought of that..and using this now !! Thanks atish :)

Comment: I am not able to open the `.msg` file in outlook using web=1 parameter. Any idea on that?