# Open Document in Edit mode programatically

Tags: document-library, document

I have bind some of the documents in grid view from Shared Document library programatically. And have kept link on the document. But when i click on the link it directly download the document. But I don't want the document to be downloaded, rather I want the behavior same as when we click on the document in Shared Document library. It opens the document in edit mode and also we can save the changes directly. How can I do this programatically.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the [OpenDocuments control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms454230(v=office.14).aspx) which is shipped with SP.js

HTML example

```
<a href=""
    onclick="editDocumentWithProgID2('http://server/site/doclib/folder/Document.docx', 
    '', 
    'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', '0', 
    'http://server/site', '0')">
    This will open the file in edit mode
</a>
```

similar question:
[editDocumentWithProgID2 in CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/161484/editdocumentwithprogid2-in-csom)

Comment: Thanks. But this is working in FireFox and IE. In Chrome I am facing an error like " we are sorry we couldn't find a program to open this document " . Can you help me for the same. Do i need any plugin or anything else??

Comment: I haven't implemented chrome support for this particular situation. you can  conditionally provide a direct link to the document, which at least will open a local copy. other than that, I can't say, but it appears that chrome has become very restrictive so if you really want to support it, you'll have to get creative